# SQL Select all entries from last two months

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, sql-server-2012

I would like to select dynamically all entries from last two months, and without entering date range in my query.

Here is my simple code:

```
SELECT Customer_Name, Date FROM table_Customer; all data between last  two month
```

Thanks in advance for your help

```
SELECT
    ME.FullName,
    R.RuleDefaultName,
    PR.ObjectName,
    PR.CounterName,
    P.DateTime,
    P.SampleCount,
    P.MinValue,
    P.MaxValue,
    P.AverageValue,
    P.StandardDeviation
FROM
    Perf.vPerfHourly P
INNER JOIN vManagedEntity ME ON
    P.ManagedEntityRowId = ME.ManagedEntityRowId
INNER JOIN vPerformanceRuleInstance PRI ON
    P.PerformanceRuleInstanceRowId = PRI.PerformanceRuleInstanceRowId
INNER JOIN vPerformanceRule PR ON
    PRI.RuleRowId = PR.RuleRowId
INNER JOIN vRule R ON
    PRI.RuleRowId = R.RuleRowId
```

Comment: SQL will not know from which column it has to compare Customers created date

Comment: This is easy, but how about telling us what column the date is in, and which server you're using?

Comment: Hello I updated my post thanks

Comment: please tag your dbms as well

Comment: Sure sorry is an 2012 microsoft sql server

Comment: You haven't defined "last two months." Is it the last 60 days or the previous two calendar months or the current month with previous month?

Answer (score 7):

```
SELECT Customer_Name, Dt
FROM table_Customer
where dt >= dateadd(day, -60, getdate())
```

Or

```
SELECT Customer_Name, Dt
FROM table_Customer
where dt >= dateadd(month, -2, getdate())
```

You should make sure not to use reserved keywords as column names.

Make sure you replace `dt` with the appropriate `date` column. The solution assumes you would need the previous 2 months data starting with the current date.

Comment: it return me an error "invalid or missing expression"

Comment: post the full query you are using

Comment: But when I add "where P.DateTime >= dateadd(month, -2, getdate())" I get this error

Comment: could you also post the structure of table `vperfhourly`?

Comment: "post the full query" would mean including the added `where` clause.

Comment: For ref, the reserved word being used here is `datetime` (T-SQL is not case-sensitive). If this isn't causing an error now, it might do so later.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select *
From Customers
Where 
    OrderDate between Dateadd(M,-2,OrderDate) And Getdate()
```